# RailsAdmin config "Add new" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

How do you config the "Add new" page in RailsAdmin?

This is my code:

```
config.model 'Car' do
    create do
        field :name
    end
end
```

I've tried create do, new do, update do, add do... none of them works

Answer (score 0):

I used CanCan to setup the user's ability.

```
can [:create, :read, :update], Car
```